# How to globally change bigcommerce default Template Layout File

Tags: bigcommerce

In my bigcommerce shop template layout file for all categories changed to default: category_with_facets.html

If there is any way to change template layout file to all categories to category.html, without editing each category manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script against the API to update `layout_file` which is apart of the [category object](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/categories). You'll just need to iterate through the category IDs.